# Android Studio Issue: Why does it still complain even if I have already updated to SDK 22?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

So I am running Android Studio v0.1 on Windows 8 (x64). When I click on New Project, it always complains:
[image]

This still happens even if I have installed the lasted SDK, latest JDK: 
[image]

Could this be my environment variables' fault?

Thank you. This stuff is new. I really don't have much clue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the right SDK directory in the settings.

Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings -> SDK's

Click the plus sign and add your Android SDK directory.

Comment: I revised my answer with the exact way to set the sdk directory.

Comment: On Mac, you want to go to File -> Other Settings -> Default Project Structure

Answer (score 0):

### Tip 1

when you set the path "ANDROID_HOME" etc make sure not to include "bin" at the end of the path. This solved the issue for me.

It works fine with JDK 1.7 (I tried with 32 bit)

if you do so, you can see the initial screen as below.
[image]

### Tip 2

Are you getting below error message?

> Your Android SDK is out of date or is missing templates. Please ensure
>   you are using SDK version 22 or later.

This error occurs probably because you have reference to your older SDK (that you downloaded with eclipse) in your path variable. Go to Environment variables and remove any reference to the old SDK folder and point it to new SDK folder that is found inside the Android Studio installation folder.

Save and restart Studio, things should work as expected now.